window.opener.document.getElementById(<%=param%>).innerHTML= myvalue not working post struts 6.3.0.2 migration
While Migration struts 2 to 6.3.0.2 version
the add document function is called with an onclick event.The window opens fine, but the element's innerHTML doesn't
get added to parent page while clicking on add button.
window.opener.document.getElementById(<%=param%>).innerHTML= myvalue 

not working.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+6.3.0.2
Param value is getting set to pageContext and able to see this value.

Did you mean to say "doesn't get added"?

Are there any errors in the console? Is the window opener in the same domain as the window? If not, they can't access each other's contents.

yes its not getting added there is no error in console but with struts 2.5.33 it works fine

The question is missing details and clarification of the problem. Also a [MCVE] is required to reproduce the issue.
